# Existence of (non) complete metric on an interval.

Tags: general-topology

I am stuck with this problem. Can anyone help me out? Thank you in advance. Question was asked in NET exam 2016 June. I am a beginner of topology. I have done b) and d). Because 0 and 1 are limit points of (0,1). If we take a sequence which converge to 0 and 1, this will be Cauchy sequence not convergent sequence w.r.t any metric. (0,1) is not a complete metric space. For example consider the sequence an=1/n→0∉(0,1) and bn=1−1/n→1∉(0,1).

[0,1]is complete. Every Cauchy sequence that converges in that interval its limit is in there. Actually it is more than complete. It is compact.
So I think b),d) are correct answers.

Which one of these are correct.

a) (0,1) with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete.

b) (0,1) with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.

c) [0,1] with the usual topology admits a metric which is not complete.

d)[0,1] with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Existence of (non) complete metric on an interval](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841043/existence-of-non-complete-metric-on-an-interval)

Comment: Instead of asking an identical question, you should rather improve the first one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841043/existence-of-non-complete-metric-on-an-interval?noredirect=1#comment3765462_1841043

Comment: To the close voters: the other question does not have an answer. As the other question is on hold and this question has been answered, I suggest we let this question supersede the other one and give the OP an opportunity to improve it.

Comment: As Peter Franek said, do not re-ask your questions when they are put on hold, edit them instead, so they can be reopened.

Comment: I have deleted the previous one. I am new here. Forgive me.

Comment: @sani Please, don't do it like this in the future: re-posting a closed question and deleting the old one seems like trying to abuse the community rules.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: As $0$ and $1$ are not elements of $(0, 1)$, your statement that a sequence that converges to $0$ or $1$ must be a Cauchy sequence is incorrect (however it is true for a a sequence that converges to $0$ or $1$ under the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$, giving an affirmative answer to (b)). For (a), find a homeomorphism between $(0, 1)$ and $\Bbb{R}$ and use it to get a metric on $(0, 1)$ that makes it complete (giving an affirmative answer to (a)). For (c) and (d), note that compact metric spaces are complete and compactness is a topological property (i.e., it is independent of the metric): the closed interval $[0, 1]$ is compact, so any metric that has $[0, 1]$ as it underlying topology is complete.

Comment: Only the usual topology is given on $(0,1)$. So you can't pull back any random metric from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so a),d) are correct ? @Rob

Comment: @Hmm. not any random metric, but certainly any metric which induces the standard topology (e.g., the Euclidean metric).

Comment: Can you explain @Jonathan

Comment: @sani Well, RobArthan has already explained to some degree. The topology doesn't uniquely determine the metric, so one can conceivably find two distinct metrics inducing the same topology, one complete and the other not. In this case, the Euclidean metric on $(0,1)$ isn't complete, as we know, but if $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, then $d(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|$ is another metric which induces the standard topology, but is complete.

Comment: Hii  @Rob  forgive me I am still not convinced

Comment: okay so all are answers are correct according to you. @jonathon

Comment: @sani that's not what I said. See RobArthan's remark concerning compactness.

Comment: So which ones are correct. Please let me know@Jonathan

Comment: @sani Let's avoid chatting in comments (they're only meant to add value to an answer). Instead, use this answer by adding to your question a discussion of why you now think each part is either correct or false; you may get more positive feedback that way. Also, if you feel Rob's answer is helpful, please consider accepting it (and/or voting it up).

Comment: @sani: as Jonathan says, the best thing for you to do now is to add you current thinking on the answers to your question (this may save it from further close votes).

Comment: I am a beginner of topology. Please let me know the answers.

Comment: Your answer isn't quite right: see my hint and Jonathan's comment.

Comment: My explanation is not correct I know. But Which ones are correct answers? Actually I am extremely concerned to it. I have done b) and d) in the exam. If my answer is correct, I will qualify. @Rob

Comment: I've updated my answer: you really should be able to work out the correct answer from what I have said now.

Comment: so according to you  correct answers are a),b),d). @Rob

Comment: Am i not right? @Rob